# Why this exception doesn't print 0?

Tags: python, exception

```
try:
    try:
        raise Exception('0')
    finally:
        print 1/0
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

It only prints out "integer division or modulo by zero". What's the procedure when the codes run?

Answer (score 5):

When a `finally` clause is present the code is executed no matter how you leave the body, i.e. by an exception or by a `return` statement.

If during the body of a `finally` there is an exception however this new exception replaces the original one and that's why the error you're getting is about 1/0 and not your original exception.

You can read more about handing errors and exceptions [in the official documentation on "defining clean-up actions"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Why this exception doesn't print 0?**
Because exception is coming in the `finally` block in statement `print 1/0`

1. A `finally` clause is always executed before leaving the try statement, whether an exception has occurred or not.

   2. The `raise` statement allows the programmer to force a specified exception to occur.

I just added `print` statement in this example:

code:

```
try:
    try:
        print "befor--raise"
        raise Exception('0')
        print "after--raise"
    finally:
        print "in finally"
        print 1/0
except Exception, e:
    print "In main Exception"
    print e


print "---------"

try:
    try:
        print "befor--raise"
        raise Exception('0')
        print "after--raise"
    finally:
        print "in finally"
        print 1/1
except Exception, e:
    print "In main Exception"
    print e
```

Output:

```
~$ python  test.py
befor--raise
in finally
In main Exception
integer division or modulo by zero
---------
befor--raise
in finally
1
In main Exception
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Becuse you `raise Exception('0')`, but not deal with it, and when the code goes for `finally`, it raise an Exception which except the outter `except`, if you try this way will see 0:

```
try:
    try:
        raise Exception('0')
    except Exception, error:
        print error
    finally:
        print 1/0
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

Output:

```
0
integer division or modulo by zero
```

Comment: Actually this isn't obvious behaviour, idk why everyone says it is.